# I have some problems with button.Click event

Tags: c#, events, button, click

I have a function `private void change ()` that I want to run when I will press a button. I have `Button schimbare = new Button();` and if I will press, to run the function.

I try `schimbare.Click += change();` but don't work. What is the good comand ?

This is the code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Programarii
{
    class InputBoxOptiuni
    {
        static TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();

        /// <summary>
        /// Displays a dialog with a prompt and textbox where the user can enter information
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="title">Dialog title</param>
        /// <param name="promptText">Dialog prompt</param>
        /// <param name="value">Sets the initial value and returns the result</param>
        /// <returns>Dialog result</returns>
        public static DialogResult Show(string title, string promptText, string informati, string mesaj, ref int ora, ref int minut30, ref int minut15, ref int douaore, ref int minut10, ref int minut5, ref int pornire2, ref int anuntare2, ref int cuparola, ref string parola, ref string email, ref int expirare, ref int cateminute, ref int vl, ref int culimba, string scurtaturi, string scurtaturi2, string format, ref int tipformat)
        {

Button schimbare = new Button();

schimbare.Click += change;

}

        private void change(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

For all that answer me, tnx.

I try with:

```
private void change(object sender, EventArgs e) and schimbare.Click += change;
```

but don't work. I try with with `schimbare.Click += (s,e)=> { //your code };`  and works !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your methods signature should be something like this:

`void change(object sender, EventArgs e)`

and write as `schimbare.Click += change;`

you can also use this syntax

```
schimbare.Click += (s,e)=>
            {
                //your code
            };
```

Comment: Tnx, I try the secound method and works perfectly. Tnx again !

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `()` - you are *subscribing* to an event handler, not invoking it (using the `()` will call `change`).

```
schimbare.Click += change;
```

Note that (apart from the non-standard naming), your `change` function should have the `EventHandler` signature (which it doesn't have - it does not take parameters), change it to:

```
private void change(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: I try with `private void change(object sender, EventArgs e)` and `schimbare.Click += change;` but I was have an error. Now work with `schimbare.Click += (s,e)=>
            {
                //your code
            };
`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
schimbare.Click += new EventHandler(this.change);
```

See also [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx) for more information.

Comment: If the signature of `change` has no parameters, this will also fail.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I provided him a link where the click event is explained in detail.

Comment: I try with private void change(object sender, EventArgs e) and schimbare.Click += change; but I was have an error. Now work with schimbare.Click += (s,e)=> { //your code };

Answer (score 0):

Wait, wait!!! You're adding return value of "change" method to the Click event! So changing the code to this should solve your problem (parentheses are extra!). I don't know the platform you are working in, please be advised that the delegate of click must have some arguments.

Cheers

```
schimbare.Click += change;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch an event like this:

```
 private void schimbare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           change();
        }
```

Hope it helps...